# Accessing the root folder in iOS 8

Tags: jailbreak, ios

I am using a iPhone 5 with iOS 8.3 and I want to have access to the root directory.

Comment: There’s no user accessible filesystem in iOS. AFAIK, you would need to jailbreak it. Perhaps an app exists, but the last time I checked, jailbreaking was the only option.

Answer (score 6):

You can't without jailbreaking. Apps run in a sandbox on iOS and can't access files outside of their containers.